‹‹ J'ai fait mieux ›› / ‹‹ J'ai mieux fait ››
In my reading of French texts I have seen both

‹‹ J'ai mieux fait ››

and

‹‹ J'ai fait mieux ››

Is there a difference of meaning, nuance or usage between the two?

J'ai mieux fait is usually followed by que or de. In the first case, it is similar to J'ai fait mieux que [...]. In the second case, it usually means that you had a choice and you selected the best option (e.g. J'ai mieux fait de venir en Belgique que d'entrer en prison, Proudhon, 1861).
J'ai fait mieux is self-sufficient, i.e. can be a full sentence by itself. It means that you did something better than someone else (or than yourself in the past).

Tu dis j'ai mieux fait de partir au présent? J'aurais tendance à utiliser l'expression au conditionnel ou au passé: je ferais mieux de partir, et j'aurais mieux fait de partir.

@Frank Oui, le conditionnel est sûrement plus courant mais la question porte sur le passé composé. Le présent serait je fais mieux de partir qui est aussi possible d'ailleurs mais là, pas de choix pour la place de l'adverbe.

Ah oui, pardon, passé composé, pas présent. Ce passé composé ne me revient pas trop, mais pourquoi pas.

Yes, there is a difference sometimes :

"J'ai fait mieux" is commonly used for comparisons between people about an action, for instance. Ex: "J'ai fait [quelque chose] mieux que lui." → "I did [something] better than him."
"J'ai mieux fait" is generally used to compare actions you did instead of something else. As an example, again: "J'ai mieux fait d'aller courir ce matin [plutôt que quelque chose d'autre ou qu'à un autre moment]." I do not know if it has any litteral translation to the english language, but it means, in a certain way : "It is a good thing I went running this morning [instead of doing something else or at another moment in time]."

Homever, both can be said like the first use I described, you can say both "J'ai mieux fait quelque chose que quelqu'un" or "J'ai fait quelque chose mieux que quelqu'un" which have the exact same meaning.

Plutôt: j'aurais mieux fait d'aller courir. Le présent sonne bizarre pour ce sens.
